# Is a heart shape convex or concave?

Tags: geometry

Is a heart shape convex or concave? To me the inward points tells me that it is concave, but according to [this](http://www.answers.com/Q/Is_a_heart_a_convex_or_concave_shape) answer, it says the inwards point makes it convex?

Comment: I agree with 5xum that the page you've linked to is wrong. Please see the ["Convex set" Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set). It is generally considered bad practice to even *call* a set "concave", even to mean "not convex". There are exceptions in the study of polygons and optics (lenses) however.

Comment: I think that whoever wrote that confused the words "concave" and "convex," forgetting which is which. It's concave, by the way.

Comment: Don't trust anything you read on the site you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart shape is not convex, because a convex set contains all the lines from any two points in the set, and the heart shape clearly does not satisfy this condition. That said, I would not call the shape concave, unless you define concave as "not convex". Functions, for example, can be either convex or concave or *both*, but I don't know of a proper definition of concavity for two-and-more dimensional sets...